# lodash _.find all matches

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have simple function to return me  object which meets my criteria.

Code looks like:

```
    var res = _.find($state.get(), function(i) {
        var match = i.name.match(re);
        return match &&
            (!i.restrict || i.restrict($rootScope.user));
    });
```

How can I find all results (not just first) which meets this criteria  but all results.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Are you looking for `_.filter`?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Just use `_.filter` - it returns all matched items.

[_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter)

> Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all elements predicate returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).

Answer (score 8):

You can use _.filter, passing in all of your requirements like so:

```
var res = _.filter($state.get(), function(i) {
        var match = i.name.match(re);
        return match &&
            (!i.restrict || i.restrict($rootScope.user));
    });
```

[Link to documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#filter)

Answer (score 8):

Without lodash using ES6, FYI:

Basic example (gets people whose age is less than 30):

```
const peopleYoungerThan30 = personArray.filter(person => person.age < 30)
```

Example using your code:

```
$state.get().filter(i => {
    var match = i.name.match(re);
    return match &&
            (!i.restrict || i.restrict($rootScope.user));
})
```